# How to import dynamic component loop with react/next

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-import

How i can use dynamic import react components in loop with NextJS:

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

function AlbumListPage({ albums }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {albums ? albums.result.COMPONENT.map(album =>
        
        dynamic(() => import(`../${album.component_url}`).then((mod) => mod), { ssr: true })
      ) : null}
    </ul>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const response = await fetch(`myapi`)
  const albums = await response.json();

  return { props: { albums } }

}

export default AlbumListPage;
}
```

I am getting compile error:

```
Failed to compile

./README.md
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> This is a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) project bootstrapped with [`create-next-app`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/create-next-app).
| 
| ## Getting Started
```

Comment: The error seems unrelated to your request. There is something else broken in your project. Are you importing the `README.md` file somewhere?

Comment: Yes, README.md i am using in my project directory, When i am importing with statically it is working without any error. But i want to use with dynamic data.

Comment: You are not understanding me correctly. The error literally says that the project fails to compile due to unrecognized module file. However, `README.md` file is **not** a module and it should normally be ignored by the compiler. Something is wrong in your project configuration or you try to import it explicitly in another file. Try deleting it, the error should change.

Comment: Check all your `album.component_url` values. There might be some wrong path causing this wrong import.

Comment: When using `next/dynamic` the path must be explicitly written, it can't be a template string or a variable. Also, `next/dynamic` should be called at the top-level of the file, and can't be called inside React rendering. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#basic-usage.